# Nginx redirects sub-folder back to root

Tags: redirect, nginx, jenkins, proxy

I have set-up with 2 dockers, one is jenkins and the other one is nginx. I want nginx to be configured to pass all movement to localhost/jenkins/ to my docker image at http://jenkins:8080...

But when i go to http://localhost/jenkins/ it redirects me to http://localhost/login?from=%2F ... it removes the "/jenkins/" part...

This is my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certificates/${SSL_CERTIFICATE_NAME}.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/${SSL_CERTIFICATE_NAME}.key;

    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_buffering    off;
    tcp_nodelay        on;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;

    location /jenkins/ {
            proxy_pass    http://jenkins:8080;
            proxy_redirect default;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is wrong... it looks like it's receiving default data because it's redirecting to "login?from=%2F" but it loses /jenkins/ subfolder...

Any help please?